# Javascript time condition between 11:40 AM and 12:20PM (11:40 < 12:20)

Tags: javascript

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var min = new Date().getMinutes();

if (hour >= 11 && hour <= 12 && min < 40 && min > 20) {
  document.body.style.background = "green";
} else {
  document.body.style.background = "red";
}
```

Comment: Did you try *literally* this code? Because there is a syntax error (extra bracket) and also you define `var hour` but try to check `hours` in the `if` condition.

Comment: `min<40 && min>20` — this will only be true when `min` is *between* 20 and 40. That's not what you need; you need to be >= 40 when hour is 11, and <= 20 when hour is 12.

Comment: @VLAZ No its just an example .I'm trying to say is it possible to set condition between 11:40 and 12:20

Comment: @AHN in the future, pleas provide code that *runs* when asking a question. Assuming that the code does actually run but the operations it does are incorrect. It is your job to provide a [mcve] not ours to try and guess which error is actually in your code and which isn't.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had three problems here:

1. the extra `}` at the end
2. `hours` is not defined. I changed it to `hour`, which is defined
3. '`=>`': this is not necessary for the hours. since you are only checking two hours (11 and 12), it's much simpler to check each hour and it's minuets separately.

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var min = new Date().getMinutes();

if((hour == 11 && min >40) || hour == 12 && min < 20) {
  document.body.style.background = "red";
} else {
  document.body.style.background = "green";
}
```

Comment: I am not running  exactly the same code. In fact, there is a problem with the condition. I am not getting the result at the right time

Comment: glad I could help :)   If you think this is the best solution, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and compare with the Date object between start time, end time and current time.

```js
const date1 = new Date();
date1.setHours(11);
date1.setMinutes(40);

const date2 = new Date();
date2.setHours(12);
date2.setMinutes(20);

const today = new Date();

if (today >= date1 && today <= date2) {
  document.body.style.background = "red";
} else {
  document.body.style.background = "green";
}
```

Comment: updated the answer again with the best practice usage of the `Date` object. @AHN

Comment: Worked fine on (12:00 PM to 12:20 PM) but didn't work on (11:40 AM to 11:59 AM)

Comment: e.g. you can setHours(11) and setMinutes(59) for the today object and test.

Answer (score 0):

This is just for this example.

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var min = new Date().getMinutes();

if (hour >= 11 && hour <= 12 && (hour === 11 ? min > 40 : min < 20)) {
  document.body.style.background = "red";
} else {
  document.body.style.background = "green";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic had some problems so I fixed them. This will change background to red if between the hours of 11:40 AM and 12:20 PM (inclusive):

```
var hour = (new Date()).getHours();
var min = (new Date()).getMinutes();

if (hour == 11 && min >= 40 || hour == 12 && min <= 20) {
  document.body.style.background = "red";
} else {
  document.body.style.background = "green";
}
```